# How can I rename the Bookmarks menu in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I am using the latest release version of Firefox, and I would like to rename the Bookmarks menu.  I don't want to rename a subfolder in the Bookmarks menu; I want to rename to Bookmarks menu itself.  Is there a way to do this, perhaps through about:config?  Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to rename the Bookmarks menu?

Comment: if you know anything about computers Firefox is written in C++, XUL, XBL, and JavaScript but the thing you want to change comes from C++ which is compiled and is in binary form... and cannot be changed...

Comment: @sleske: I'm helping an older gentleman who is in the early stages of dementia with his computer.  I switched him to Firefox because his eyesight is poor, even with his glasses, and the zoom feature on IE is terrible.  I wanted to rename the Bookmarks menu to Favorites because that is what he is used to.  The plugin I found adds a Favorites menu, which is even better in this situation because then he will have two paths to find what he is looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the information. I hope you'll be able to help him.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe I found a suitable plugin.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/668/

Comment: That's sorta what you asked but not really...

Answer (score 1):

I am nearly 99% sure that its compiled into the software and cannot be changed without editing the source files and recompiling.

Comment: I am a software engineer by profession, so that may be an option.  Do you have any pointers on how I can get my hands on Firefox's source code?

Comment: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/firefox/